# Why Readable.push() return false every time Readable._read() is called

Tags: node.js

I have the following readable stream in typescript:

```
import {Readable} from "stream";

enum InputState {
    NOT_READABLE,
    READABLE,
    ENDED
}

export class Aggregator extends Readable {

    private inputs: Array<NodeJS.ReadableStream>;
    private states: Array<InputState>;
    private records: Array<any>;

    constructor(options, inputs: Array<NodeJS.ReadableStream>) {
        // force object mode
        options.objectMode = true;

        super(options);

        this.inputs = inputs;

        // set initial state
        this.states = this.inputs.map(() => InputState.NOT_READABLE);
        this.records = this.inputs.map(() => null);

        // register event handlers for input streams
        this.inputs.forEach((input, i) => {
            input.on("readable", () => {
                console.log("input", i, "readable event fired");

                this.states[i] = InputState.READABLE;

                if (this._readable) { this.emit("_readable"); }
            });

            input.on("end", () => {
                console.log("input", i, "end event fired");

                this.states[i] = InputState.ENDED;

                // if (this._end) { this.push(null); return; }

                if (this._readable) { this.emit("_readable"); }
            });
        });
    }

    get _readable () {
        return this.states.every(
            state => state === InputState.READABLE ||
            state === InputState.ENDED);
    }

    get _end () {
        return this.states.every(state => state === InputState.ENDED);
    }

    _aggregate () {
        console.log("calling _aggregate");

        let timestamp = Infinity,
            indexes = [];

        console.log("initial record state", JSON.stringify(this.records));

        this.records.forEach((record, i) => {
            // try to read missing records
            if (!this.records[i] && this.states[i] !== InputState.ENDED) {
                this.records[i] = this.inputs[i].read();

                if (!this.records[i]) {
                    this.states[i] = InputState.NOT_READABLE;
                    return;
                }
            }

            // update timestamp if a better one is found
            if (this.records[i] && timestamp > this.records[i].t) {
                timestamp = this.records[i].t;

                // clean the indexes array
                indexes.length = 0;
            }

            // include the record index if has the required timestamp
            if (this.records[i] && this.records[i].t === timestamp) {
                indexes.push(i);
            }
        });

        console.log("final record state", JSON.stringify(this.records), indexes, timestamp);

        // end prematurely if after trying to read inputs the aggregator is
        // not ready
        if (!this._readable) {
            console.log("end prematurely trying to read inputs", this.states);
            this.push(null);
            return;
        }

        // end prematurely if all inputs are ended and there is no remaining
        // record values
        if (this._end && indexes.length === 0) {
            console.log("end on empty indexes", this.states);
            this.push(null);
            return;
        }

        // create the aggregated record
        let record = {
            t: timestamp,
            v: this.records.map(
                (r, i) => indexes.indexOf(i) !== -1 ? r.v : null
            )
        };

        console.log("aggregated record", JSON.stringify(record));

        if (this.push(record)) {
            console.log("record pushed downstream");
            // remove records already aggregated and pushed
            indexes.forEach(i => { this.records[i] = null; });

            this.records.forEach((record, i) => {
                // try to read missing records
                if (!this.records[i] && this.states[i] !== InputState.ENDED) {
                    this.records[i] = this.inputs[i].read();

                    if (!this.records[i]) {
                        this.states[i] = InputState.NOT_READABLE;
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("record failed to push downstream");
        }
    }

    _read () {
        console.log("calling _read", this._readable);
        if (this._readable) { this._aggregate(); }
        else {
            this.once("_readable", this._aggregate.bind(this));
        }
    }
}
```

It is designed to aggregate multiple input streams in object mode. In the end it aggregate multiple time series data streams into a single one. The problem i'm facing is that when i test the feature i'm seeing repeatedly the message `record failed to push downstream` and immediately the message `calling _read true` and in between just the 3 messages related to the aggregation algorithm. So the Readable stream machinery is calling _read and every time it's failing the push() call. Any idea why is this happening? Did you know of a library that implement this kind of algorithm or a better way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer myself the question.

The problem was that i was misunderstanding the meaning of the `this.push()` return value call. I think a false return value mean that the current push operation fail but the real meaning is that the next push operation will fail.

A simple fix to the code shown above is to replace this:

```
if (this.push(record)) {
    console.log("record pushed downstream");
    // remove records already aggregated and pushed
    indexes.forEach(i => { this.records[i] = null; });

    this.records.forEach((record, i) => {
        // try to read missing records
        if (!this.records[i] && this.states[i] !== InputState.ENDED) {
            this.records[i] = this.inputs[i].read();

            if (!this.records[i]) {
                this.states[i] = InputState.NOT_READABLE;
            }
        }
    });
} else {
    console.log("record failed to push downstream");
}
```

By this:

```
this.push(record);
console.log("record pushed downstream");
// remove records already aggregated and pushed
indexes.forEach(i => { this.records[i] = null; });

this.records.forEach((record, i) => {
    // try to read missing records
    if (!this.records[i] && this.states[i] !== InputState.ENDED) {
        this.records[i] = this.inputs[i].read();

        if (!this.records[i]) {
            this.states[i] = InputState.NOT_READABLE;
        }
    }
});
```

You can notice that the only difference is avoid conditioning operations on the return value of the `this.push()` call. Given that the current implementation call `this.push()` only once per `_read()` call this simple change solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It means feeding is faster than consuming. The official approach is enlarge its highWaterMark, Default: 16384 (16KB), or 16 for objectMode. As long as its inner buffer is big enough, the push function will always return true. It does not have to be single push() in single _read(). You may push as much as the `highWaterMark` indicates in a single _read().